# How to make a case return a different value if a variable is true in swift?

Tags: swift, if-statement, enums, return

I was wondering if I could have a case statement return a different value if a variable was true or false.

```
var variable = false
enum enumeraton {
    case thing
    var value: Int {
        switch self {
        case .thing:
            if variable = true {
                return 1
            }else {
                return 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Yes you can. You just need to access "Variable" from where you call `value`. So maybe make a function (`func value(withVariable: Bool) -> Int`), or access it from the method (a singleton?)

Comment: Shouldn't your `if-else` be `if variable == true` you seem to be missing an equals sign in the condition

Comment: Yes! Thank you Larme, that worked great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that could work. Tested with Xcode 12.5 and Swift 5.4

```swift
var variable = false
enum enumeraton {
    case thing
    case other
    var value: Int {
        switch self {
        case .thing:
            if variable {
                return 1
            } else {
                return 2
            }
        case .other:
            return 0
        }
    }
}

let foo = enumeraton.thing
print(foo.value) //prints 2

variable = true
print(foo.value) //prints 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you want to treat `variable` there are different solutions. If you want to read the value of `variable` when creating your enum variable/property you can use an associated value with the enum

```
var variable = false
enum Enumeraton {
    case thing(Bool)
    var value: Int {
        switch self {
        case .thing(let flag):
            return flag ? 1 : 2
        }
    }
}

let enumValue: Enumeraton = .thing(variable)
print(enumValue.value)
```

But if you want to read `variable` over time then a function that takes the boolean as an argument is better

```
enum Enumeraton {
    case thing

    func value(for flag: Bool) -> Int {
        guard self == .thing else { return 0 } // or some other action
        return flag ? 1 : 2
    }
}

let enumValue: Enumeraton = .thing
print(enumValue.value(for: variable))
```